# Inserting a column & text within new cells (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013, trying to insert a new column at the start of my sheet (Column A) & then insert text into the newly created cells. I would like to insert the word "OR" into every new cell created from row 1 all the way down to the last row that contains data within my sheet. The amount of rows in the sheet will change daily so ideally I would like the code to auto detect the amount of rows if possible rather than the code having to be changed daily.

I have searched for the answer on here & can find how to insert a new column or text but I can't find the specific code required for my above issue.

Any help would greatly be appreciated please

Comment: Sounds like you're close, can you share the code you have?

Comment: Start by recording a macro to accomplish your task.  Then clean it up. After that, if you can't get it working, edit your post to show your code, data example, and where you have run into problems. It might be helpful to read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks to both for your replies. Below is what I have so far. My issue is the range. The amount of rows will change daily. The current code is set to insert text up to & including row 42. I would like it to insert text for every row where data is present.

Comment: Sub Macro1()'' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+R
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OR"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A42"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:A42").Select
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following, it will count the number of rows in Column A, then insert a new Column and enter "OR" on each cell from Row 2 to Last:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data on Column A
    ws.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    'insert new column A
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    'set range from A2 to Last, amend if your data has no headers and you want to insert "OR" into A1 too.
    rng.Value = "OR"
    'add the value "OR" to each cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Xabier. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I really appreciate that you have also explained what each line is

Comment: @Manos, please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)